# Why is the CFM56 produced with two different thrust reverse options?

Tags: jet-engine, thrust-reverser

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56#Reverse_thrust), the CFM56 could support several reverse thrust options, and it appears that it has actually been built with 2:

- Boeing seems to prefer the cascade type
- Airbus seems to prefer the pivoting door type

Is this a simple case of catering to customer preferences, or is there a more in-depth reason for having multiple reverse thrust options?

Comment: On a turbofan the reverser is usually [part of the nacelle](http://aii.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Thrust-Reverser-3.jpg), not of the engine.

Comment: … and the nacelle has to be designed for every aircraft+engine combination anyway, so choosing different reversers in different cases does not really add much extra work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

> Hispano-Suiza has delivered the world's first target-door reverser for a big turbofan, the A320's CFM56

The extending petal-shaped doors type is a [Hispano-Suiza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispano-Suiza) specialty. It's a French company and one of the three major suppliers of reverse systems.

In the 80's Hispano-Suiza had to be innovative to capture a bigger market share. Their door type was the first ever on a high bypass engine. They believed investing in R&D will help increase their sales (it did). The petal reversers also double as airbrakes.

[image]

#### Why not on the Boeing 737?

Since the CFM56 on the 737 is close to the ground, the doors would scrape the pavement. And—more importantly for other aircraft types—Hispano-Suiza's competitors are [Rohr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohr,_Inc.) and Boeing. Boeing definitely would like to keep things in-house with their translating/cascading reversers.

Nowadays with the jet engines of the smallest regional jets to the wide-bodies being as wide as the fuselages, the cascading type is the better choice.

---

Sources:

- Flight, [1986 / 1600](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1986/1986%20-%201600.PDF)
- Flight, [1994 / 0230](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1994/1994%20-%200230.PDF)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely to allow for increase installation flexibility depending on the choice of engine cowlings to be used on a given aircraft design.